# Genetic Algorithm in cryptography

Tags: encryption, cryptography, key, genetic-algorithm, encryption-symmetric

Can anyone explain how genetic algorithms can be used in cryptography?
Genetic algorithms are optimizing problems, and they use some kind of pseudorandom code as key. How this key can be transferred to the receiver?

Answer (score -1):

They are unlikely to be of much use in general.  Genetic algorithms rely on a reasonably small change in output for a small change in input -- that allows them to close in on a good solution to the problem.

Cryptographic algorithms are designed to have a large change in output for a small change in input.  A good hash algorithm will flip around half the output bits if a single input bit is changed.

That makes genetic algorithms in general little better than a brute force search.